# Passing extra data to find_or_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Something I've always wondered about rails is the ability to pass extra data to find_or_create methods in rails. For example, I can't do the following

```
User.find_or_create_by_name('ceilingfish', :email => 'an_email@a.domain', :legs => true, :face => false)
```

I could do

```
u = User.find_or_create_by_name('ceilingfish')
u.update_attributes(:email => 'an_email@a.domain', :legs => true, :face => false)
```

But that's uglier, and also requires three queries. I suppose I could do

```
User.find_or_create_by_name_and_email_and_face_and_legs('ceilingfish','an_email@a.domain',true, false)
```

But that kind of implies that I know what the values of `email`, `legs` and `face` are. Does anyone know if there's a really elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.find_or_create_by_name(:name=>'ceilingfish', 
        :email => 'an_email@a.domain', :legs => true, :face => false)
```

When you have additional parameters to `find_or_create_by_`, you have to pass all the parameters as a hash.

#### Rails 4

```
  User.create_with(
    email: 'an_email@a.domain', 
    legs: true, face:false
  ).find_or_create_by(:name=>'ceilingfish')
```

Comment: Wow that's awesome, thanks Kandada, the only quirk I have noticed is that if any of the attributes are invalid (say in the above example email had a validation pattern that checked for a proper tld), then none of the following attributes are set (so legs and face would still be nil)

Comment: @Ceilingfish: It's actually a bug that your first form doesn't work. http://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4457-find_or_create_by_foo-when-foo-is-protected-attribute

Comment: In case of existing user, **:email**, **:legs** and **:face** elements will not be updated.

Comment: @guiding5 that is why the function is called `find_or_create_by_`. The user is created only when the user doesn't exist, otherwise the user found using the keys is returned.

Comment: What about now? DEPRECATION WARNING: This dynamic method is deprecated. Please use e.g. Post.find_or_create_by(name: 'foo') instead.

Comment: @Philip I have updated my answer to include a rails 4 section.

Comment: @HarishShetty - Great, I also added a answer =)

Answer (score 1):

With rails 4.x

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: This dynamic method is deprecated. Please use e.g. Post.find_or_create_by(name: 'foo') instead
```

Use this

```
User.find_or_create_by(first_name: 'Scarlett') do |user|
  user.last_name = 'Johansson'
end
```