# Association id = nil when using find_or_create_by

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

When I try adding a Client through the find_or_create_by method I don`t get a trainer_id passed in as an value (trainer_id for client = nil)

Even thou in my Client_Controller I have the the build method, which I assume would pull the id from current_trainer

I'm assuming there's a disconnect between find_or_create_by_name & build method.

Would appreciate any help with this.

**Client_Controller**

```
 def create
    @client = current_trainer.clients.build(params[:client])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.save
        ClientMailer.registration_confirmation(@client).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @client, :notice => 'Client was successfully added.' }
        format.json { render :json => @client, :status => :created, :location => @client }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @client.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Workout Model**

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :client
    belongs_to :trainer

    validates_presence_of   :day, 
                            :client_id, 
                            :trainer_id, 
                            :message => "You have to indicated for when you want to schedule this workout."
    def client_name
        client.try(:name)
    end

    def client_name=(name)
        self.client = Client.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
    end

end
```

**Client Model**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :trainer

    before_save :generate_password

    has_many :workouts
    has_many :weigh_ins

    validates_presence_of   :name, :message => "You have to provide a client name in order to add new client."

    has_attached_file :profile_pic, :styles => { :micro => "60x60>", :small => "150x150>" }, 
                                    :default_url => 'profile_default_small.jpg',
                                    :storage => :s3,
                                    :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS,
                                    :bucket => '#',
                                    :path => ":attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

    validates_attachment_size   :profile_pic, 
                                :less_than => 3.megabytes,  
                                :message => "Your profile picture can`t be bigger than 3MB, sorry."

    def generate_password
        self.password = name[0..2].to_s + rand(99).to_s
    end

    def self.authenticate(email, password)  
        client = find_by_email(email)  
        if client && client.password == client.password
          client  
        else  
          nil  
        end
    end
```

**Server Log**

```
  Started POST "/workouts" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Apr 25 17:39:37 -0400 2012
    Processing by WorkoutsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"commit"=>"Schedule Session", "authenticity_token"=>"CxJSVfn0fwerdyrpA9/JEe8fX8Ep2/ZhnOqQkjZ3iwE=", "utf8"=>"✓", "workout"=>{"client_name"=>"John Doe", "day(1i)"=>"2012", "day(2i)"=>"4", "day(3i)"=>"29", "day(4i)"=>"21", "day(5i)"=>"00", "note"=>"", "title"=>"Current_Client"}}
      Trainer Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "trainers".* FROM "trainers" WHERE "trainers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 37]]
      Client Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."name" = 'John Doe' LIMIT 1
       (0.0ms)  begin transaction
      SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "clients" ("created_at", "email", "goal_weight", "name", "notes", "password", "profile_pic_content_type", "profile_pic_file_name", "profile_pic_file_size", "profile_pic_updated_at", "start_weight", "trainer_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 25 Apr 2012 21:39:37 UTC +00:00], ["email", nil], ["goal_weight", nil], ["name", "John Doe"], ["notes", nil], ["password", "Joh55"], ["profile_pic_content_type", nil], ["profile_pic_file_name", nil], ["profile_pic_file_size", nil], ["profile_pic_updated_at", nil], ["start_weight", nil], ["trainer_id", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 25 Apr 2012 21:39:37 UTC +00:00]]
    [paperclip] Saving attachments.
       (2.3ms)  commit transaction
       (0.1ms)  begin transaction
      SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "workouts" ("client_id", "created_at", "day", "note", "title", "trainer_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["client_id", 53], ["created_at", Wed, 25 Apr 2012 21:39:37 UTC +00:00], ["day", Sun, 29 Apr 2012 21:00:00 UTC +00:00], ["note", ""], ["title", "Current_Client"], ["trainer_id", 37], ["updated_at", Wed, 25 Apr 2012 21:39:37 UTC +00:00]]
       (1.1ms)  commit transaction
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/workouts/64
    Completed 302 Found in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)
```

Comment: What does your `Client` class look like? Are you using `attr_protected` or `attr_accessible` in it?

Comment: Not using any attributes at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, `find_or_create_by` is going to use the `create` method, not your create controller action. That's why none of the other information is  making it into the new `Client` record.

You can pass additional parameters to `find_or_create_by_name`. These parameters will either be 1) ignored if a record is found or 2) used in the `create` method if no record is found. You need to pass the `create` the additional parameters for your relationships because it won't automagically handle them the way `build` does.

You want something like this: `find_or_create_by_name(:name => name, :trainer_id => self.trainer_id)`. Note that when using additional params, you need to pass them all as a hash.

More info: [Passing extra data to find_or_create](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2394489/1005071)

Comment: I found that somewhere earlier, but when I implement that I get an error: "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id". I know that @current_trainer.id is not nil.

Comment: If you used `@current_trainer` then it wouldn't work because there is no `@current_trainer` inside of your Workout model. You need to access it inside the Workout model by using something like `self.trainer_id`. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I`ve managed to find some hack to overcome this differently (http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models)