# How to defer execution of expensive create_by option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

The following question is almost *exactly* what I need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2394783/456188

I'd like to run the following:

```
find_or_create_by_person_id(:person_id => 10, :some_other => expensive_query)
```

But more importantly, I'd like to defer the execution of `expensive_query` **unless** I actually have to create the object.

Is that possible with find_or_create_by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `find_or_create_by*` accepts a block that only gets run in the `create` case.

```
find_or_create_by_person_id(10) do |item|
    item.some_other = expensive_query
end
```